# Write a NESTED LOOP code segment that produces this output

Tags: java, loops, nested

I know there is another thread with the same name, but the answer isn't really the one I'm looking for.

I can only use for loops. The other answer uses complex syntax like:

```
reverse = !reverse ? i == max : reverse;

i = reverse ? i-1 : i+1;
```

Can it be simpler than that?

Thanks a lot.

So, this is the output.

I can only get until 4 I don't know how to keep from there...

```
1

1 2

1 2 3

1 2 3 4

1 2 3

1 2

1
```

This is what I have so far:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i=1;i<=4;i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) System.out.print(j+" ");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    for(int i=4;i>=1;i--){
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) System.out.print(j+" ");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

}

but my output is the following:

1

1 2

1 2 3

1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4

1 2 3

1 2

1

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: Do the outer loop from 1 until max - 1, the inner loop from outer to min(outer, max - outer)

Comment: I think I don't get what you are trying to say. I'm sorry I'm just new at this programming stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi
i have done using the below code

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
            int j,i;
            int max=4;
            int n=0;
            for(i=0;i<((max*2)-1);i++)
            {
                    if(i<max)
                     n++;
                    else
                     n--;
                    for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
                    {
                            System.out.print(j+" ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
            }
    }
}
```

The below is the output
[image]
You can generalize it for any number i hope this is fine

Answer (score 0):

Your two outer loops are:

```
for(int i=1;i<=4;i++) {
for(int i=4;i>=1;i--) {
```

This will generate the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1. If you want to only have one 4-length row in the output, change the second loop to:

```
for(int i=3;i>=1;i--) {
```

so that it starts from 3, instead of 4. The problem is that currently, both your outer loops generate the value 4 right after one another.